# actualizar un textview desde una base de datos Firebase cuando se presiona un boton

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

lo que necesito es que un textview se actualice cuando un dato de la base Firebase cambia. Esto ocurre cuando presionas un botón en la app.

Entonces tengo el textview

```
db.collection("basededatos").document("gestion").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            val estado2 = it.data?.get("estado").toString()

            estado.text = estado2
        }
```

con esto me conecto a la base de datos consigo el estado y se imprime en el textview llamado "estado"

luego están los botones que cambian esta información en la base de datos

```
activar.setOnClickListener{
            val act = "activado"
            db.collection("basededatos").document("gestion").update(hashMapOf("estado" to act)
                    as Map<String, Any>)
        }

        desactivar.setOnClickListener{
            val desact = "desactivado"
            db.collection("basededatos").document("gestion").update(hashMapOf("estado" to desact)
                    as Map<String, Any>)
        }
```

todo funciona bien, solo que el textview no se actualiza al momento de presionar el botón, tengo que cambiar de activity y volver a esta para que aparezca la info actualizada

Quedo atento a su ayuda ... ¡gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En este caso debes usar el listener [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) y dentro del método [onDataChange](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener#onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot)) puedes llamar a cambiar el texto, ya que este método es llamado cada vez que la información cambia.

```
.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener){
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
       ...
       ...
        estado.text = estado2
       ...
       ...
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        //Post failed!
    }
}
```